# Mean value theorem trick question

Tags: calculus

I've encountered this question:

True or False. If f is continuous on [2,4], f′ exists on (2,4), and
f′(c) = f(4) − f(2)/2 , then c ∈ (2, 4).

My first guess was that it's right. It seems to follow the rules of the MVT.
But I was told that it's a trick question and that it's in fact false. I can't see why.. Could anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: You have a typo.It should read $ (f(4)-f(2)/2.$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f: x \mapsto x: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$; then $f$ satisfies the conditions; but $f'(x) = 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

The trickiness of the question is mainly in that the MVT has absolutely nothing to do with it. I think it's called a false syllogism. In easier terms you know (MVT) "every dog has fur", you are told ($f^\prime(c)=(f(4)-f(2))/2$) "this mammal has fur" and you are told to conclude ($c\in (2,4)$) "this mammal is a dog".

The Mean value theorem only tells you that if some things are true, (derivative exists and the function is continuous at end points) then something else must be true (there must exist a $c$ in the interval such that the derivative is equal to the slope of the secant through the end points). It says absolutely nothing about where arbitrary $c$'s at which the derivative happens to be equal to the slope of the secant must lie.

Comment: Hmm I'll try to understand that. btw, I was also told to try to think of function where c isn't necessarily in (2;4). Can you think of one? Maybe a rational function?

Comment: The trick is that the domain of $f$ was not specified, This tricks you into assuming that the domain of $f$ is $[2,4]$.

Comment: But the function is continuous on [2,4], doesn't this imply that the function spans over this interval?

Comment: @ArthurRimbaud It means that it at least spans the interval. It says nothing about whether it is or is not defined elsewhere. Moreover even if the domain was restricted strictly to $[2,4]$ there is nothing preventing the $c$ to be either $2$ or $4$ thus not being in $(2,4)$. What I was pointing out in the answer is that MVT says there $\exists c\in (a,b)\;\; P(c)$ and the question is attempting to use it as $\forall c (P(c)\implies c\in(a,b))$

Comment: Actually rereading my answer it doesn't really correctly create the analogy with the dog. This is due to the fact that the MVT is a bit more complex then just if $A$ then $B$ (eventhough at the highest level this is true). It's really if $P(f,a,b)\wedge Q(f,a,b)$ then $\exists c (R(c,a,b)\wedge S(c,f,a,b))$ where $P$ is $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, $Q$ is $f$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$, $R$ is $c\in (a,b)$ and $S$ is $f^\prime(c)=(f(b)-f(a))/2$. So you get there exists a $c$ satisfying two things. The question is using it as if $c$ satisfies $S$ then it satisfies $R$. Which is wrong.